# How to edit layout of a particular post format?

Tags: posts, post-formats, add-theme-support

I'm looking to edit my theme layout of the *aside* post format.

I have already included the `add_theme_support()` function to include the aside option when creating a post. However, the layout of an *aside* does not look good. I wish to style it pretty much identically to the *video* format.

Which file in my theme represents the *aside* post format layout?

Comment: In what context? Only a post format archive has a [specific template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies). Other contexts are theme-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you would just make CSS changes. For example, a post that has the `aside` format will have included in it's mark-up a class of `format-aside` which you could override in your own CSS, whether it be by way of child theme support or CSS plugin.

I've only just been playing with this today (incidentally, which is how I came across this question).

**Example:**
You could hide the title of posts tagged with the `quote` post-format (ie `format-quote`) by including this in your CSS file:

```
.home .format-quote .entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

This would then format that entry on your blog page / index to not include the title from the post, and would make the quote just appear as more of an inline quote between two posts.

Or you could include a background image or custom colour behind the post based on the format.

I haven't completed it yet, but I'm working on a format to use the post title as the author of a quote, and the content to be the quote content, and the position the title under the quote in smaller than `<h2>` tags, or possibly just add an `::after` element to maybe include the word "says" or "said" so that the quote field could be presented thus:

> ### Isaac Newton said:
>
> I can calculate the motion of heavenly bodies, but not the madness of people.

There isn't a plethora of information out there, but here are a couple of links which go into a little further detail (the first being WordPress Codex):

[WordPress Codex page on Post Formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/User:Chipbennett/Post_Formats)
[Elegant Themes Blog post: Creating Post Formats](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-wordpress-post-formats)

Answer (score 1):

You could edit some code in `single.php` file by using `get_post_format()` function to check your post format and show anything you want to show for each post format.

For example:

```
if ( get_post_format( get_the_ID() ) == 'aside' ) {
   // Show something different from another template here!!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a template part for it named `content-aside.php` and use a conditional in `single.php` to call it:

```
if ( is_singular( 'aside' ) ) {
   get_template_part( 'content', 'aside');
} else {
   get_template_part( 'content', 'single');
}
```

A simple `get_template_part()` may do it too:

```
   if ( is_singular() ) {
      get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );
   }
```